# Angular web worker not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, setinterval, web-worker

I am trying to create a countdown timer.

I am using web-worker which changes the value of a variable using setInterval and then sends it via postMessage to the script file which then updates a scope variable.

It successfully updates the variable for 10-15 times. **But it stops updating after that.**

**I have created this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/C9Ev2K?p=preview) Check the countdown value it stops working after 85 or so.**

***script.js***

```
angular
  .module('App', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) { 
      $scope.time = 100;

      var worker = new Worker('worker.js');


      worker.onmessage = function(e) {
      $scope.time = e.data.time;
      $scope.$apply();
      };

     worker.postMessage($scope.time);

}]);
```

***worker.js***

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
  var time = e.data;

  var timer = setInterval(toDo, 1000);


  function toDo() {

    time = time - 1;
    //console.log(time);
    postMessage({
    time: time
});
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `worker` became undefined after some time (maybe js garbage collector).

To avoid that, you can keep the worker as part of your $scope.

change  this line:

```
 var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

To this one:

```
 $scope.worker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

In [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/JyNVoi8xsjl3R65EO5lT?p=preview) fork, you plunkr is working.

Comment: it would be also good to encapsulate to-worker communcation into the Angular service and communicate to it from the controller via its interface